# Creating multiple requests to webservice at android

Tags: android, rest, asynchronous

I have a RestService which gives me list of another service links.

While I need to process each of this serviceUrl's and get its object that contains type and value. My final list will be image, NameOfTheRestObject, Value, Type. 
For doing this, after getting restobject, i'm looping through each object then with a `AsyncTask` executing get method. But when doing this, making requests to different services, Activity is getting laggy or sometimes because of one of requests, application crashes completely instead of returning null of single request.If i dont add `get()` at for loop, loop continues without getting data from service.
Any suggestions for how can i improve this?

```
   {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Name of the Method",
        "serviceUrl": "/api/StatisticMethod/Statistic1",
        "imageUrl": "fa-tree.png",
        "isActive": true
    }

   DataValue dv = new getStatistics().execute(serviceUrl).get(); 

   private class getStatistics extends AsyncTask<String, DataValue, DataValue> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected DataValue doInBackground(String... arg0) {
        HttpHandler sh = new HttpHandler();
        valueData = new DataValue("", "");
        String url = arg0[0];
        String data = sh.makeServiceCall(url, true, context);
        try {
            if (!AppHelper.isNullOrEmpty(data)) {
                JSONObject js = new JSONObject(data);
                String value = js.getString("value");
                String valueType = js.getString("valueType");

                valueData = new DataValue(value, valueType);
                return valueData;
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Log.e(TAG, "doInBackground: ", ex);
            return valueData;
        }

        return valueData;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(DataValue result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
    }
}
```

`

Comment: you want to execute multiple requests go with service(bind) or scheduler if your trying to do this using async it will kill app performance.

Comment: Yes, even if i add timeout to my HttpHandler's UrlConnection, if i get more than 20 request, my waiting time becomes nearly 3-4 sec.

Answer (score 1):

Likely it lags because of the call to `.get()` - if you want to do it this way, you'd instead have to call back *asynchronously*, which requires defining an `interface` and passing an instance of it's implementation into the constructor of `AsyncTask` (for example, in order to display a progress bar, once the number of calls is known). Better use Retrofit and map a model class with GSON converter. If all responses look the same, a single model suffices, else you'd need a model for each kind of response. Given the example JSON, this would look about like this:

```
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;

public class Device {

    @SerializedName("id")
    private int id;

    @SerializedName("name")
    private String name;

    @SerializedName("serviceUrl")
    private String serviceUrl;

    @SerializedName("imageUrl")
    private String imageUrl;

    @SerializedName("isActive")
    private boolean isActive;

    public void setId(@NonNull int value) {
        this.id = value;
    }
    public void setName(@NonNull String value) {
        this.name = value;
    }
    public void setServiceUrl(@NonNull String value) {
        this.serviceUrl = value;
    }
    public void setImageUrl(@NonNull String value) {
        this.imageUrl = value;
    }
    public void setIsActive(@NonNull boolean value) {
        this.isActive = value;
    }

    @NonNull
    public int getId() {
        return this.id;
    }
    @NonNull
    public String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }
    @NonNull
    public String getServiceUrl() {
        return this.serviceUrl;
    }
    @NonNull
    public String getImageUrl() {
        return this.imageUrl;
    }
    @NonNull
    public boolean getIsActive() {
        return this.isActive;
    }
}
```

The same goes for class `DataValue`.

Comment: I'm already getting first list with retrofit, but on creating interfaces, i dont know which services or which service links will be get thereafter. Thats why after getting first list with retrofit, i had to go through each line and collect their data's with creating new connection with HttpUrlConnection and then parse its JSON data

Comment: @Kuroiteiken you don't need any service, but need to run it asynchronously. an `interface` (definition) just provides the interface between `AsyncTask` and the caller class, which `implements` that `interface`. See [Supercharging Retrofit with Generics, Adapters & Callbacks](https://medium.com/artisans-of-tech/supercharging-retrofit-with-generics-adapters-callbacks-51ae57618a0) (in particular, the Callbacks part). On the first call you'll know the amount of calls and on the following calls you then can call back with `i++` on a progress bar, report errors and alike.